# Why am I not able to use the DatastoreService class? App Engine SDK not installed correctly?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I added a new AppEngine Module to my project and it works so far. The AppEngine is installed, but i can't import any com.google.* packages, so I guess, I did something wrong. I can't figure out what.

I can use all the javax.servlet.http.* stuff of course, but I can't use the DatastoreService-class for some reason.

The AppEngine is obviously installed, otherwise I would not be able to add an AppEngine Module, but something still seems to be missing.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.18'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.31'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
}

appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing build.gradle to this:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.17'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.17'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.17'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.17'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
}

appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
}
```